# How to store data locally in React Native that is not a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, local-storage

I am looking for a way to store objects and arrays of data locally in React Native. How can this be done? Looking at the api for AsyncStorage:

static **setItem**(key: string, value: string, callback?: ?(error: ?Error) => void)
  *Sets value for key and calls callback on completion, along with an Error if there is any. Returns a Promise object.*

How do I store objects and arrays locally in React Native?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

JSON.stringify({}) can be used to convert your data structure to a string.

You'd then use JSON.parse() to convert the string back to the original data structure.

You could create a nice service for this to eliminate some boilerplate code throughout your app. I've used React Native's built-in AsyncStorage API as the "persistent" storage facility in the example below. Adapt it as you see fit.

**Example using React Native**

Using the JSON API to store an object in persistent storage, i.e. React Native's AyncStorage, and then retrieving that value, and outputting it in a Text element. Untested.

Storage.js file - Note, this example object API provides a *subset* wrapper around what ReactNative's AsyncStorage API provides, you could adapt it to allow setting multiple keys for example, rather than one at a time.

```
//./storage.js
const Storage = {

    getItem: async function (key) {
        let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        //You'd want to error check for failed JSON parsing...
        return JSON.parse(item);
    },
    setItem: async function (key, value) {
        return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    removeItem: async function (key) {
        return await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
};
```

React Native component

```
//Usage...
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Storage from "./storage";

class Foo extends Component {

    constructor (props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            greeting: ""
        };
    } 

    async componentDidMount () {

        await Storage.setItem("someObj", {value: "bar", id: 1});

        let obj = await Storage.getItem("someObj");

        this.setState({
             greeting: obj.value // Will be "bar" 
        });

    }

    render () {

         return (
               <View>
                    <Text>{this.state.greeting}</Text>
               </View>
         );
    }
}
```

**Original example:**

As I originally answered this on mobile, I did originally use the HTML5 localStorage api as an example, it was quicker to type (and it was cold!), here it is just in-case someone lands on this for react, not react-native mistakenly.

```
var StorageService = function  () {};

StorageService.prototype.get = function (key) {
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
};

StorageService.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
    return window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
};
```

Comment: @NaderDabit if you don't want to have to worry about JSON.stringify and JSON.parse I would suggest [react-native-simple-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-store). Takes some of the boilerplate out of AsyncStorage.

Comment: @jasonmerino dude, your comment should be the best answer.

Comment: Wait, using a third party component should be yh accepted answer, when a few lines of vanilla js will do the job? :/

Comment: Nice Lee. Missing closing parentheses after JSON.stringify(value)

Comment: How can i store and download a pdf file in react-native

Answer (score 1):

recently i write pleex, you can take look at it https://github.com/E-RROR/pleex.
you can save data in pure json or creating schemas with typechecking feature and more.
thanks

Comment: Please consider providing more information about how to use your library instead of only linking to it.